# Libname Connection to SAS Access to Redshift throwing CLI error

Tags: sas, amazon-redshift

We recently got *SAS Access to Redshift* license and are trying to connect to Redshift database directly without ODBC. 
This is the libname statement I am using

```
libname A1 redshift server='XXX' port=5439 user='YYYY' password='ZZZZ'  Database='RRRR';
```

It is however throwing the following error

> ERROR: CLI error trying to establish connection: [unixODBC][Driver
>   Manager]Can't open lib 'SAS ACCESS to Amazon Redshift' : file not
>   found ERROR: Error in the LIBNAME statement.

Are there any configurations we need to do before using SAS Access to Redshift?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What version of SAS do you have installed (including maintenance release #)?

Comment: @joe the current version is 9.04.01M4P110916

Comment: Have you talked to SAS Tech Support? After all, the expensive license fee does come with dedicated support and the response time should be better than here for these topics.

Comment: Verify the license installation via proc setinit and product_status. Then try specifying the schema as per the documentation.And remove extra quotes if not necessary.

Comment: I'd be more concerned the product itself isn't installed - maybe it wasn't selected when installation occurred initially.  I would consider running the installer to check if the product is installed (you should be able to verify this).

Answer (score 1):

Yes - you need to configure your ODBC settings.

You can find a very detailed guide [here](https://communities.sas.com/t5/SAS-Communities-Library/Successfully-configuring-an-ODBC-driver-to-access-Redshift-from/ta-p/223987) and additional guidance [here](https://support.sas.com/documentation/installcenter/en/ikfdtnunxcg/66380/PDF/default/config.pdf)